# datastax LDAP config error "Unable to find property"

Tags: cassandra, ldap, datastax

I have installed dse 5.1 testing 2 node cassandra cluster which working fine.

I need to configure LDAP Authentication.

Below is my dse.yaml file and cassandra .yaml file

=========================

server_host: hostname
server_port: 389
search_dn: cn=username
search_password: ldappassword
user_search_base: dc=test,dc=testdomain,dc=com
user_memberof_attribute: member
group_search_type: directory_search#
group_search_filter: (&(cn=*)(objectclass=group))
group_name_attribute: cn
credentials_validity_in_ms: 0
connection_pool:
max_active: 8
max_idle: 8

========================================

cassandra.yaml

authenticator: com.datastax.bdp.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.LdapAuthenticator
authorizer: com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.DseAuthorizer

role_manager: com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.DseRoleManager
roles_validity_in_ms: 2000

dse version

[root@hostname)dse -v
5.1.3
[root@hostname dse]#

=========================================

Error i am getting

====================================================

ned_function_warn_timeout=500; user_function_timeout_policy=die; windows_timer_interval=1; write_request_timeout_in_ms=2000]
INFO  [main] 2017-10-18 09:45:54,428  DatabaseDescriptor.java:368 - DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
INFO  [main] 2017-10-18 09:45:54,428  DatabaseDescriptor.java:422 - Global memtable on-heap threshold is enabled at 8192MB
INFO  [main] 2017-10-18 09:45:54,428  DatabaseDescriptor.java:426 - Global memtable off-heap threshold is enabled at 8192MB
INFO  [main] 2017-10-18 09:45:54,447  RateBasedBackPressure.java:123 - Initialized back-pressure with high ratio: 0.9, factor: 5, flow: FAST,
 window size: 2000.
INFO  [main] 2017-10-18 09:45:54,447  DatabaseDescriptor.java:718 - Back-pressure is disabled with strategy org.apache.cassandra.net.RateBase
dBackPressure{high_ratio=0.9, factor=5, flow=FAST}.
INFO  [main] 2017-10-18 09:45:54,468  DseDelegateSnitch.java:40 - Setting my workloads to [Analytics, Cassandra]
INFO  [main] 2017-10-18 09:45:54,473  DseConfigYamlLoader.java:38 - Loading settings from file:/etc/dse/dse.yaml
ERROR [main] 2017-10-18 09:45:54,516  DseModule.java:109 - Unable to start server. Exiting..
org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: Unable to find property 'server_host' on class: com.datastax.bdp.config.Config
        at com.datastax.bdp.config.DseYamlPropertyUtils.getProperty(DseYamlPropertyUtils.java:70) ~[dse-core-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.introspector.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.java:121) ~[snakeyaml-1.12.jar:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.getProperty(Constructor.java:308) ~[snakeyaml-1.12.jar:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.constructJavaBean2ndStep(Constructor.java:240) ~[snakeyaml-1.12.jar:na
]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.construct(Constructor.java:189) ~[snakeyaml-1.12.jar:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructYamlObject.construct(Constructor.java:331) ~[snakeyaml-1.12.jar:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObject(BaseConstructor.java:182) ~[snakeyaml-1.12.jar:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructDocument(BaseConstructor.java:141) ~[snakeyaml-1.12.jar:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getSingleData(BaseConstructor.java:127) ~[snakeyaml-1.12.jar:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadFromReader(Yaml.java:481) ~[snakeyaml-1.12.jar:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadAs(Yaml.java:475) ~[snakeyaml-1.12.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.bdp.config.DseConfigYamlLoader.(DseConfigYamlLoader.java:57) ~[dse-core-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
        at com.datastax.bdp.snitch.DseDelegateSnitch.(DseDelegateSnitch.java:41) ~[dse-core-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.construct(FBUtilities.java:525) ~[cassandra-all-3.11.0.1855.jar:3.11.0.1855]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.construct(FBUtilities.java:518) ~[cassandra-all-3.11.0.1855.jar:3.11.0.1855]
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.createEndpointSnitch(DatabaseDescriptor.java:1028) ~[cassandra-all-3.11.0.1855.jar::

==============================================================

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you removed the parent key `ldap_options` for all the LDAP options in `dse.yaml`. All of those sub-keys you specified need to be nested under the `ldap_options` root key.